# Tor browser browsing history

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, server-administration

i just want to know if the browsing history of Tor browser being detected at the firewall of the domain ?

for example , i at the office and i connect to internet using tor browser.. my work station is connected to the company's domain, is my browsing history traceable (see) by the system administrator who's handling the firewall?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not, because he can't decipher your Tor connections **on firewall**. However it does not prevents him from installing spyware on enpoint machines "to trace things down". But you can be safely ensured that there's NO trace possible on firewall logs alone: your browsing history from properly configured Tor can not be there.